# Standardized beta for logistic regressionin R

Tags: r, logistic

For my survey data analysis, I ran an Ordinal Logistic regression using the 'polr' function.
The summary of the regression is as follows:

[image]

My question is:

1. Do I need to standardize my  beta values?
2. If so, is lm.beta the right approach (as per my understanding, it only works for linear models)? And if not, could you please provide a method to do so.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

If any of your predictors are continuous, you appear to be assuming effects are linear, which is a bigger problem.

In general, I find standardized estimates confusing and the choice of standardization arbitrary.  I like to stick to real scales.

Comment: My predictors are basically responses on an ordinal scale (Poor to Excellent, 1 to 5). If my understanding is correct, linear regression cannot (and should not) be applied to such a dataset.That is why I am going with ordinal. Am I correct?

Comment: Ordinal regression is ordinal because of how it treats $Y$.  The $X$'s can be any old mixture of data.  But if any $X$ is ordinal, treating it as linear, while sometimes necessary because we don't have that many ways to deal with it, is not optimal.